# Cannot send email using Microsoft Graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

This is the new error message that I am encountering now. When trying out graph explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to execute office 365 APIs using my company account, I am encountering an error below when using APIs for Outlook Mail and Calendar. Same error encountered for the applications that I have downloaded in Github. Applications that are trying to access the calendar APIs. I have also tried to create a developer account for office 365 and it has the same error message when accessing the APIs.

It looks like an access issue and/or admin privilege is needed.

Error response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "351f57d5-3bdb-4c6f-a06c-b204f23d0eda",
            "date": "2018-06-13T03:12:28"
        }
    }
}

But I can access User APIs. Like getting my profile details in OSM AD.
Successful response:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "987f2dcf-a66c-4f14-a180-41e2eac0b65c",
    "businessPhones": [
        "+47 37 50 46 15"
    ],
    "displayName": "Teemee F Tang",
    "givenName": "Teemee F",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": "Teemee.Tang@osm.no",
    "mobilePhone": "+63 947 33 71109",
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Tang",
    "userPrincipalName": "Teemee.Tang@osm.no"
}

Comment: Hello, could you please share more details of which permission you set (+ whether they are application permission or delegated ones), whether you granted them and whether your access token decoded using e.g. https://jwt.io contains the required role. Please also specify which flow you are using to acquire access token.

Comment: Are you able to access your mailbox using [Outlook for the web](https://outlook.office.com/owa)?

Comment: I updated the description of my error.

Answer (score 0):

I just login my account in https://outlook.office365.com. After that I can already use my company account with Microsoft Graph.